# Rebase a percentage calculation based upon the initial calculated percentages

Tags: finance, percentages

I've got a set of figures that I want to track the percentage change for and then throw away the figures and just hold the calculate percentage movements.

Easy so far!

Now the trickier bit.. I want to then be able to re-base my percentage changes against any of the figures in my list.

So for example:

```
Figures:                 1     2    4     4     8   16   6   3   5   2
Percentage Increase:     0   100  300   300   700 1500 500 200 400 100

Re-based figures on '8': 8    16    6     3     5    2
Percentage Increase:     0   100  -25 -62.5 -37.5  -75
```

My question, is how can I work out from the initial percentages alone, what the percentage changes should be following my re-base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to add $100$ to each of the percentage increases, then calculate the percentage increase of these numbers.  In your example, we'd have 
$$\matrix{\text{Figures} &800 &1600 &600 &300 &500 &200\\
\text{Pct. Increase} &0   &100  &-25 &-62.5 &-37.5  &-75}$$